# Why does my response from endpoint in .NET 6 API always change to an empty array?

Tags: c#, json, .net-6.0

I am creating a post type endpoint to create a record, but the answer, whether correct or incorrect, changes the result to an empty array.

this is the endpoint

```
[HttpPost("CrearRol")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CrearRol(Role rol)
        {
            var x = await _roles.CrearRol(rol);
            return x;
        }
```

And this is de method CrearRol

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CrearRol(Role rol)
        {
            try
            {
                var roleBuscado = _context.Roles.Where(e => e.NombreRol == rol.NombreRol.Trim() && e.Estado== "A").FirstOrDefault();
                if (roleBuscado != null)
                {
                    return _error.respuestaDeError("El rol '"+rol.NombreRol+"' ya existe");
                }
                Role rolNuevo = new Role();
                rolNuevo.NombreRol = rol.NombreRol;
                rolNuevo.UsuarioIng = rol.UsuarioIng;
                rolNuevo.FechaIng = DateTime.Now;
                rolNuevo.Estado = "A";
                _context.Roles.Add(rolNuevo);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                JObject respuesta = new JObject
                {
                    ["message"] = 1
                };
                return new ObjectResult(respuesta) { StatusCode = 200 };

            }catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return _error.respuestaDeError("Error al momento de crear el rol", ex);
            }
        }
```

Succes responce

```
{
  "message": []
}
```

Error responce

```
{
    "error": []
}
```

when you debug the response this is displayed correctly like this
Correct Succes responce

```
{
    "message": "succes save"
}
```

Correct Error responce

```
{
    "error": "string with error information"
}
```

I try from postman, insomnia, swagger, angular and the responce is always bad

Comment: My guess is that the problem is that `JObject` is from Newtonsoft.Json, but you're using System.Text.Json serialization. If you want to use JObject, I would make sure you use Newtonsoft.Json consistently. See https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/ and https://makolyte.com/aspdotnet-how-to-make-the-controllers-use-newtonsoft/

Comment: I suggest returning `new { message = 1 }` instead, since that will actually generate a class at compile time, and that will be understood whichever serializer you're using. P.S. I've removed your Entity Framework tags as this question isn't about EF.

Comment: @Jon Skeet If that's really the problem. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct answer is in the comments of the first post. But I'll also put it here

Add this nuget package in your proyect

Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson

In my case version 6 but it may vary depending on your .net version

And add '.AddNewtonsoftJson();' in your program.cs,
in this way:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
return Ok( new { message=1 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the support, however I can't return an OK() or a BadRequest() because the methods are in different files. Previously I worked in .net 5.0 and this way it worked for me without problems, I don't know if it is a .net 6.0 configuration